# How to implement google tag manager in ionic 5 with capacitor app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5, angular11

I want to use GTM (Google Tag Manager) in my ionic5 capacitor Android/IOS app, I have tried the
[cordova-plugin-tag-manager](https://github.com/kraihn/cordova-plugin-tag-manager)

but don't know how to make it work with ionic5.

Can you please suggest any other option which is compatible with both android and IOS?

I am using capacitor: 2.4.4 and ionic: 5.4.16

Comment: Check: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics

Comment: Thanks! I have installed this plugin but still, no data received is there any other configuration I have to do?